# Sizes of consecutive elements of the indiscernible club of $a$, get collapsed to the same cardinality in $L[a^\#]$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

This question arises from a proof in Kanamori's "The Higher Infinite". To get started, assume that $a^\#$ exists for every $a \in \omega^\omega$. Also for any $a \in \omega^\omega$, let $I_a$ denote the corresponding club of indiscernibles that generate $L[a]$. And also note that for any $a$, $I_{a^\#} \subseteq I_a$.

Now the question is that what happens to successor elements of $I_a$ in $L[a^\#]$. And the claim is that if $\langle \xi_\alpha: \alpha \in \text{On}\rangle$ is the monotone enumeration of $I_a$, then in $L[a^\#]$ for any $\alpha$, $|\xi_{\alpha}| = |\xi_{\alpha+1}|$.

**Note**. This claim is used for $\xi_\alpha \lt \aleph_\omega$, but since there was no emphasis on it, I think it holds in general.

I have thus far showed that for any $\alpha$, $\xi_{\alpha+1} \not \in I_{a^\#}$. But this is not enough as $L[a^\#]$ has many cardinals that are not indiscernible.

I would appreciate any hints or solutions for this.

Minor side note. You can assume the background theory to be ZF + AD + DC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of $a^{\#}$ implies that every uncountable cardinal is a limit member of the club of $a$-indiscernibles.  If you apply that fact within the model $L[a^{\#}]$, you'll get the result  you wanted.

Comment: Oh, this was much easier than I expected! I guess the main point that I was missing was that we get all of the theory related to $a^\#$ inside $L[a^\#]$ by absoluteness. Thanks!